# Problem in installing packages due to convertdate installtion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytz

> ERROR: convertdate 2.2.0 has requirement pytz<2020,>=2014.10, but
>   you'll have pytz 2020.1 which is incompatible.

This error comes up when I try to install my packages.

These are the other requirements

```
    'certifi   >=   2019.11.28',
    'cffi   >=      1.14.0',
    'chardet   >=   3.0.4',
    'click   >=     7.1.1',
    'cryptography   >=     2.8',
    'Faker   >=     4.0.2',
    'holidays   >=      0.10.1',
    'idna  >=   2.9',
    'jwt  >=   1.0.0',
    'numpy  >=   1.18.2',
    'pandas  >=   1.0.3',
    'pycparser  >=   2.20',
    'PyJWT  >=   1.7.1',
    'PyMeeus  >=   0.3.7',
    'python-dateutil  >=   2.8.1',
    'pytictoc  >=   1.5.0',
    'requests  >=   2.23.0',
    'six  >=   1.14.0',
    'soupsieve  >=   2.0',
    'text-unidecode  >=   1.3',
    'urllib3  >=   1.25.8'
```

Comment: This is probably a dependency version conflict. But without more info like what are the other requirements, we cannot help you further.

Comment: @SamuelNLP have added them please have a look

Comment: The "upper limit" of pytz will be removed soon if [this merge request](https://github.com/fitnr/convertdate/pull/27) goes through.